# How to run Anki source codes .py from VScode?

Tags: anki

sorry I am a new developer, and new to Anki development, I am trying to figure out the source code from \pylib\anki,  and when I run the source code for example collection.py, it shows this error when I run(from original code: `from anki import ( card_rendering_pb2, collection_pb2, config_pb2, generic_pb2, import_export_pb2, links_pb2, search_pb2, stats_pb2, )`)

Anki collection.py

[image: 1]

could anyone tell me how should I solve this issue? I also try to set up Ubuntu to change the environment configuration.
thank you so much. I find the Anki development manual confusing and can't figure out how I should set up VScode for the Anki environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `aqt`, through `pip` for example: `pip3 install aqt[qt6]`. The whole setup is explained in [the manual](https://addon-docs.ankiweb.net/editor-setup.html).

---

Incidentally, you might want to read the [section on ProtoBuf in the architecture description of Anki](https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/main/docs/architecture.md#protobuf), where it explicitly says

> At the moment, **the protobuf is not considered public API**. Some pylib methods expose a protobuf object directly to callers, but when they do so, they use a type alias, so **callers outside pylib should never need to import a generated _pb2.py file**.

Comment: thank you, i already installed through pip3. and follow the manual. so most likely they use alias. do i need to change anything to call the _pb2,p? or is basically cant be called through the regular way?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use these modules at all, which is probably why you can't import them. If you want more information, I'd recommend going on the [official forums](forums.ankiweb.net), where you can find lots of both add-on developers and the actual Anki developers, so they will be able to tell you the right way to do what you are trying to do (which I unfortunately can't).